# Converting C# app to Android - How to extend List<>

Tags: c#, java

I'm converting an app someone else wrote to Android.

One of the classes is declared like so:

```
public class PowerList : List<PowerEvent>
```

How would I do this in Java for Android? If I do this:

```
public class PowerList extends List<PowerEvent>
```

I get errors -

```java
"The type List<PowerEvent> cannot be the superclass of PowerList; a superclass must be a class"
```

Comment: What errors do you have? can you add more information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

List is an interface rather than an extendable class. You could try extending ArrayList instead.

Answer (score 7):

`List` is an interface in `Java`. You could use `ArrayList<T>` which is an implemented class of `List`

Answer (score 2):

you should try `ArrayList<PowerEvent>`